# how to MERGE sorted values together with the name that comes together with the value?

Tags: java

```
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
    Map<Double,String> m = new HashMap<Double,String>();

    String pre = "abc";
    String post = ".txt";
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++) {
        m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
    }
    SortedSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(m.keySet());
    for (Double d : set) {
        System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
    }
    }
```

Example output :

```
The resulting similarity score of the query how [INITIAL OUTPUT]

abc0.txt = 0.5773502691896258

abc1.txt = 0.5773502691896258

abc2.txt = 0.5773502691896258

abc3.txt = NaN

abc4.txt = 0.5773502691896258

abc5.txt = NaN

abc6.txt = NaN

abc7.txt = NaN

abc8.txt = NaN

abc9.txt = 0.5773502691896258

abc10.txt = NaN

Similarity score sorted **DESIRED** output :


0.5773502691896258   abc0.txt

0.5773502691896258   abc1.txt

0.5773502691896258   abc2.txt

0.5773502691896258   abc4.txt

0.5773502691896258   abc9.txt

NaN                  abc3.txt

NaN                  abc5.txt

NaN                  abc6.txt

NaN                  abc7.txt

NaN                  abc8.txt

NaN                  abc10.txt
```

How do i make the text files to merge with the similarity score even ofter sorted ? In another sense, even after sorting, the output display each individual text file follow their individual score.

Comment: This is just an aside, but assuming `_resultArea` is a `StringBuilder`, it is foolish to use `_resultArea.append(someStr + someOtherStr)`. The compiler will create a new StringBuilder just for the purpose of appending `someStr` to `someOtherStr`. You are better off doing `_resultArea.append(someStr).append(someOtherStr);` Yay Builder pattern!! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the easiest (or most straightforward) would be to use a collection and a comparator.

Put the values in a Map, then sort on the double. That may even be the natural sort order so you don't have to write a comparator.

```
Map<Double,String> m = new HashMap<Double,String>();

String pre = "abc";
String post = ".txt";
for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
    m.put(Math.random(),pre + ii + post);
}
SortedSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(m.keySet());
for (Double d : set) {
    System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
}
```

This returns a sorted output (low to high) and you could easily reverse it or run through it a different way.

-- edit to show using OP's modified code:

```
// Initialize variables
String pre = "abc";
String post = ".txt";
Map<Double,String> m = new HashMap<Double,String>();

// Add data to your map
for (int a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
   m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
}

// sort the map keyset and print out the sorted results
SortedSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(m.keySet());
for (int ii = set.size(); ii >= 0; --ii) {
   System.out.println(set.get(ii) + " " + m.get(d));
}
```

Comment: hi, i edited my program according to your suggestion but it seems that it does not sort the value i am having. Would you point my mistakes ? Thanks.

Comment: Your for loops are nested incorrectly. If you're going to loop over the file at the top, you don't need to loop over them inside. You're effectively adding the same "score" to a hash multiple times in the first interior for loop. In the second interior for loop, you're sorting only the values that already exist in the map. Worst, you're creating the map /inside/ your for loop ... so you're creating a map, adding one value to it several times (which in a map will only add one value), sorting one value, then printing one value. Then doing it again and again.